# Why doesn't data load on page_load?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0

I have a **button** whose text (**a counter on datatable**) should be changed when I click Update or Add button. 
But it doesn't. It only does when I refresh the page only, why ?

Button are within UpdatePanel.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    DataTable dt = ShowLastHearingDates();

    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
          btnShowLasthearingDates.Text = dt.Rows.Count.ToString();
    }
```

update:

```
protected void btnupdate_click(object sender, Eventargs e)
{
     if (MngCaseHearings.UpdateCaseANDHearingDetails(CaseNo, CaseTitle))
                {

                    btnUpdate.Visible = false;
                    btnAddCaseAndHearingDetails.Visible = true;


                }
}
```

Comment: What you are doing on update\add button click? Show that code too.

Comment: @RahulSingh check please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is that the page load event happens before your update occurs. You can put the code in the page prerender event which will be hit after the page load and control event

Answer (score -1):

- try to put UpdateMode to "always"
- or put all related control in the samne panal
- or put AsyncPostBackTrigger
  this urls my help
  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386454.aspx
  http://code.runnable.com/UhmIdrdIZy9aAATR/how-to-use-updatepanel-in-asp-net

Comment: put
if(! ispostback)

and put the same code in page load in btnupdate_click